# Проблема при установке Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio

Здравствуйте, решения проблемы нигде не нашел, поэтому пишу сюда. Удалил предыдущую версию VS и решил поставить Visual Studio 2015 Community, при этом возникла данная ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя у меня и был установлен .NET Framework 4.6.1, решил его переустановить, не помогло, после поставил версию 4.6.2, но изменений никаких не было.

[image: В программах и компонентах]

Надеюсь, что кто-нибудь может подсказать решение проблемы, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему удалось решить лишь переустановкой Windows.